# Application not running out of Eclipse, but from command line

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a strange problem with a java application and Eclipse. The application is supposed to have 6 TCP/IP connections. Now i run it out of Eclipse, and only 2 of the partners are connecting. I export it and run it from command line, still the same. I add -Xm1024m as VM parameter, as seen in a batch file, run it out of command line, and all partners connect. I add this parameter to Eclipse, but still only 2 connect.

I'm running both on Windows 7 and Java 7. The computer is freshly installed. On the previous computer everything run fine. The Eclipse version is the same. There is one difference i found: The new Eclipse complains about import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec, which the previous installation did not. But the previos installation run the sam: Windows 7 and Java 7.

The source code is terrible, not invented by me. I'm only the "lucky" guy who has to maintain it. Here is just the small snipped where it hangs:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        Socket ss = sServer.accept();
        Thread server = new ServerBody(ss, this, mainframe);
        server.setName("ServerBody:" + ss.getInetAddress().toString());
        server.start();
        ServerDescription sd = new ServerDescription(ss, server);
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, server.getName() + " connected", "connect", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // DEBUG
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        [...]
    } 
    catch (IllegalBlockingModeException e) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

While debugging i found that it passes 2 times the accept() method, then the third time it hangs here (no more incoming connection). No Exception is thrown!
Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be and/or how i can get rid of it? It is obviously not a code problem, but some kind of Eclipse setup or some other setup.

Comment: Could you please add the code you left out with [...] too?

Comment: Socket ss = sServer.accept();
      
//      ss.setKeepAlive(true);    // Good or bad? Check.
      Thread server = new ServerBody(ss, this, mainframe);
      server.setName("ServerBody:" + ss.getInetAddress().toString());
      server.start();
      ServerDescription sd = new ServerDescription(ss, server);
      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, server.getName() + " connected", "connect", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); // DEBUG
      servers.put(ss.getInetAddress().toString(), sd);

Comment: Sorry, i'll try to format it better soon :) But for now: No, the application does not exit. Everything which does not depend on these 4 connections works. The accept() is called and never returns.

Comment: It's my first question here. It is difficult to find my way through this jungle :)

Comment: No Problem, we are here to help :) You are using a `sServer` and `ServerDescription`. Do you have the Code of them also?

Comment: method `accept()` blocks because there is no new connection coming. Are you sure there are 4 connections?

Comment: true, and otherwise, try to set the `socketTimeout` to 0 -> Infinite

Comment: sServer is simple: sServer = new ServerSocket(8189); The ServerDescription is a bit more, but basically just a struct with the socket, the thread ID, and some accessors. It is just needed to observe these connections after they once came in. From time to time these connections get lost (heavy machinery behind it), so they reconnect. I just put it into a HashMap and go through it in another thread to get a message if any of these server threads at some point crashes. Nothing sophisticated, but all in all some lines. And i don't know how to post them here in a readable format.

Comment: @grape_mao: Yes, i am. There are 6 machines supposed to connect to this application. Or, precise: 5 machines and the application itself. The application itself connects first. Then one of the machines. Then nothing more. But these other connections are coming in if i start the app from command line and with -Xm1024m.

Comment: sorry, did see that...Add the parameters in run configuration of eclipse maybe?

Comment: @NoRelect: I don't know if the accept timeout is already infinite. But even if it would not be, this is an endless loop, so there would be another accept if there would be a timeout. The problem does not lie in this piece of code. The problem is, as grape_mao stated, there is no more connection coming. But why? They are supposed to, and when run from command line with -Xm1024m, they _are_ coming in.

Comment: @grape_mao: I tried. I set them generally set them in Windows - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs, and i set them in project properties. Nothing changed. This is why i'm asking here. Adding these parameters i already found elsewhere here :)